# Network fails when workstation powered off

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have a network of about 50 PC's connected through an HP Proliant switch, with Cisco routers. There are 4 workstations that exhibit some very strange behavior. When you power any one of the computers down, it brings the network to a grinding halt. There's approximately a 90% packet drop rate. This lasts until you either disconnect the computer from the network via yanking the cable or powering the computer back up. Any ideas?

Comment: Are these Dell machines?

Comment: What kind of machines are thees? Or better, what exact NIC chipset are they using?

Comment: They are Dell machines. It's in a detached office, so I'm having the onsite tech gather the info for me.

Comment: How hard would it be to stuff a brand new NIC adapter in the machine and disable the existing one?

Comment: Try turning off Wake on Lan in the BIOS, if possible.

Comment: It turns out that it's only one computer and it's a Dell Dimension 9200. According to the Dell website, it has an Intel 825xx gigabit network controller onboard.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at/replace the network cables and cards from these machines.  It's possible that when the power is off they're shorting the pins in an incorrect manner, causing a loop or noise on the ethernet.